# Defining methods on the fly in Ruby / Rails - how to set params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-methods, dynamic-method

I am trying to define a set of functions where I can pass in given params.

for example, how do i do the following?

```
>> get_1_type("xxx")

V4_RELATIONSHIP_TYPES=[1=>2,3=>4]

V4_RELATIONSHIP_TYPES.keys.each do |key|
 self.class.send(:define_method, "get_#{key}_type".downcase) do
  return GuidInfo.get_or_new(PARAMS, V4_RELATIONSHIP_TYPES[key])
 end
end

# i can call -> get_1_type("xxx") , and get the function called
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
V4_RELATIONSHIP_TYPES.keys.each do |key|
 self.class.send(:define_method, "get_#{key}_type".downcase) do |param|
  # use param
  return GuidInfo.get_or_new(PARAMS, V4_RELATIONSHIP_TYPES[key])
 end
end
```

Now you can invoke the method with a parameter:

```
get_1_type("xxx")
```

**Edit 1**

Some links about Ruby blocks:

[Start with this one](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/07/the-building-blocks-of-ruby/)

[Link 1](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/using-ruby-blocks-and-rolling-your-own-iterators/)

[Link 2](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/)

Comment: thanks, this is great! Do you mind explaining what this is really doing? In particular, I do not get how the block works

Comment: Block is used as the method body and the block parameters are used as the method parameters.

Comment: thanks a lot! Still getting my head around block, yield, etc. How did you become proficient in it?

Comment: Google, Rails source code. I have updated my answer with few links to articles about Ruby blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would create a method that way instead of just opening up the class again and inserting your method, but you could use `class_eval` instead:

```
self.class.class_eval %Q{
  def get_#{key.downcase}_type(...)
    ...
  end
}
```